# Products of Ideals $I=(a,b), J=(b,c)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If $R$ is a ring with identity $1\neq 0$, and Ideals $I=(a,b),J=(b,c), a,b,c\in R$ is it true that
$$
IJ =(a,b)(b,c)=(ab, ac, b^2, bc)
$$
I know it holds for principal ideals (so $(a)(b)=(ab)$) but I'm not sure if it holds in general. I tried to prove it by writing $I=(a)+(b), J=(b)+(c)$ and then
$$
IJ=((a)+(b))((b)+(c))=(ab)+(ac)+(b^2)+(bc)=(ab,ac,b^2,bc)
$$
but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\,A = (a)\,$ etc. Then applying the [ideal distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158533/242) $$\begin{align} (a,b)(b.c) &= (A+B)(B+C)\\ &= (A+B)B + (A+B)C\\  &= AB+BB+AC+BC\\  &= (ab)+(bb)+(ac)+(bc)\\ &= (ab,bb,ac,bc)\end{align}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ The same equality is true if you read $\,(a,b)\,$ as a gcd because - like ideals - gcds also satisfy the associative, commutative and distributive laws (the same notation is used in order to exploit this commonality, e.g. we can [give proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056382/242) that work for both gcds and ideals if we use only these common laws).

Comment: Thank you! Also, the remark about the gcd is really interesting. I thought it was just abusive notation...

Comment: @14159 See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242) for the same question about gcds.

Comment: @14159 See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3056382/242) for more on the motivation for the common notation for gcds and ideals.